# Key-value data in application

Tags: database-design, project-management

What is the best way to manage key-value data which is used in other tables.

Every table for new type or one table which contains additional attribute which distinguish between different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table per type - see [OTLT and EAV: the two big design mistakes all beginners make](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html) for my views on one table for all lookups.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't disagree with Tony Andrews (and I upvoted his answer) but I would say that as with most database design questions, the answer is "it depends".

In this case, it depends on what type of values you are talking about here.  If the key-value portion of your system is very generic and could potentially be used to hold almost anything, especially important business facts, then Tony's warnings against OTLT are very well taken.

If, on the other hand, you are looking at a relatively restricted domain of keys and values, i.e. a list of status codes that might appear in a variety of master tables or transaction tables, then the dangers of OTLT are not severe.  In fact, OTLT can be helpful for these types of code lookups when your system requires internationalization and your keys give you different values depending on the current language selection.  Keep in mind that these acceptable scenarios are not truly "OTLT", insofar as you're multiple purpose lookup table is not *all purpose*.  Limiting the scope to specific code lookups is fine.  Trying to replace your DMBS with EAV and OTLT is a bad idea for the reasons Tony described in his blog.